# Create local directory when dealing with remote servers

Tags: bash, command-line, mkdir

I am copying files from a FTP server to the file system of my cluster. The script is executed on the cluster.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='0.0.0.0' # Host IP
ftp -i -nv $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $FTPUSER
quote PASS $FTPPASS
binary

cd /FTPDIR/path/to/data/
mkdir -p /home/admin/path/to/data/
lcd /home/admin/path/to/data/
```

I added the `mkdir -p /home/admin/path/to/data/` command in order to create the directory in my cluster in case it does not exists. However, the script created a directory named `-p` in the FTP `/FTPDIR/path/to/data/` dir.

What would be the command to create it in the cluster?

Comment: The `mkdir` you are calling here is not the `mkdir` that exists on your system (or on the target system either), it is the `mkdir` that FTP provides.  And that `mkdir` does not have the `-p` option.  You have to create each directory one by one, no shortcut.

Comment: Got it, that explains by the `-p` folder was being created on the cwd, thank you sir. You can post an answer and I will mark it as correct @Nic3500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mkdir` you are calling here is not the `mkdir` that exists on your system (or on the target system either).  It is the `mkdir` that FTP provides. And that `mkdir` does not have the `-p` option.

You have to create each directory one by one, no shortcut.